# Getting exact location in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I have written Swift code for current location but the code isn't giving me the exact location as Android use to locate.

For me it just give me the Country location pointing but I need the exact location for my application.

Here is my code for location

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
class location: UIViewController , CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var address : String = "" 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()  
        //let dataProvider = GoogleDataProvider(            
        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
        {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    var start : CLLocation!
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        start = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: start!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: start!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
        self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)      
        print("function called")

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        annotation.coordinate = center
        annotation.title  = "You are Here :)" 
        map.addAnnotation(annotation)
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {
            placemarks, error in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if let pm = placemarks?.first {
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            }
            else
            {
                print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: You are testing on simulator or device? If you are testing on simulator it will not show exact location. Use actual device.

Comment: but when i give the .gpx file it locate according to the coordinates given...

Comment: You need to consider iOS != android. MapKit does not work as google maps iOS SDK does.

Comment: Thanks a lot for information... :)

Comment: So you're saying that the text info you see only shows the country? What about the annotation shown on the map? Where is the code that displays the address of the location? In the code you posted it looks like you're calling a method `displayLocationInfo()`. Post that code if you need help improving it.